# How do you search and print multiple matches per line with grep -o?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, markdown

I have a mkdocs instance and am writing a script to print internal links in a page. I cannot get grep to print only the matches if there are multiple per line.

This is what I currently have:

```
$ grep -Eon '\[([[:alpha:]]|[[:digit:]]|[[:space:]])*\]\((\/|\.).*\)' /path/to/file.md
10:[foo](../../relative_path/foobar.md) is the path to another file, also see [bar](/absolute/path/foobar.md)
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
10:[foo](../../relative_path/foobar.md)
10:[bar](/absolute/path/foobar.md)
```

Is there a way to do this in grep or even another command like awk or sed?

Answer (score 6):

```
grep -Pno "[[[:alnum:]]*]\(.*?\)" /path/to/file.md
```

OR even better( this would match even *["foo anotherword"]*)

```
grep -Pno "\[([[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]*)*?\]\(.*?\)"
```

`-P` => Perl Regex which is used to match non-greedy using `?`

OR if *don't want* only alpha numeric and space but **any character** means

```
 grep -Pno "\[.*?\]\(.*?\)"
```

Comment: Stalin, this seems to be what user binarysta has answered, but you dropped some constraints that OP used, such as `[[:space:]]` and `\/|\.`

Comment: @Quasímodo :I answered it long back with -P option before binarysta, I just edited for some other thing.or may be in draft i don't know but was typing even before your answer  ...It seems OP is looking for absolute or relative path , i think this would work...

Comment: what is the reason for omitting`[[:space:]]` from the OP's pattern?

Comment: @binarysta bcz OP is using | inside ( and ) that matches  either only spaces or digits or alphas which makes no sense ...

Comment: Ando so you down voted ? :(

Comment: @StalinVigneshKumar what do you mean makes no sense? we do not know the input. maybe there are `[space foo]` patterns.

Comment: @binarysta : that would also print in the answer i provided after OR.

Comment: oh yes, you've edited. please make a small edit because my vote is blocked, i will upvote it.

Comment: @binarysta : Thanks much

Answer (score 4):

```
\[([[:alpha:]]|[[:digit:]]|[[:space:]])*\]
```

would match `[foo]`, that is OK. The mistake is that after it comes:

```
\((\/|\.).*\)
```

You need to be careful when you include `.*` in your regexes, because it is very, very greedy! That will match `(../../relative_path/foobar.md) is the path to another file, also see [bar](/absolute/path/foobar.md)`. Concatenating, the whole line has been matched.

You should go for

```
grep -Eon '\[([[:alnum:]]|[[:space:]])*\]\((\.|\/)[^)]*\)'
```

The key was to replace `.*` by `[^)]*`, requiring the latter regex to stop short when if a closing parenthesis comes in its way. Also, I've applied this change:

- `[[:alpha:]]|[[:digit:]]` can be collapsed into `[[:alnum:]]`

Output:

```
1:[foo](../../relative_path/foobar.md)
1:[bar](/absolute/path/foobar.md)
```

(I have `1:` instead of `10:` because it is the first line in my file.)

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -on '\[[^]]*\]([^)]*)'
```

May just be enough in your case. Do you really need to restrict what characters may occur within `[...]` and `(...)`?

If you want to require the part inside `[...]` to only be made of alnums or whitespace and the part inside `(...)` to start with either a `/` or a `.`, that would simply be:

```
grep -on '\[[[:alnum:][:space:]]*\]([./][^)]*)'
```

In any case, note the `[^)]*` instead of `.*)` as `.*` would swallow the closing `)` and everything up to the right-most `)` on the line.

No need for `-E`'s `|` alternation operator here. To match a single character, you can use the `[set]` bracket expression, where the `set` can include several characters or character classes (here `[:alnum:]`, short for `[:alpha:][:digit:]` and `[:space:]`).

Answer (score 2):

Need to use non-greedy grep

Added `?` after `.*` in `((\/|\.).*?\)`

```
grep -Pon '\[([[:alpha:]]|[[:digit:]]|[[:space:]])*\]\((\/|\.).*?\)' /path/to/file.md

10:[foo](../../relative_path/foobar.md)
10:[bar](/absolute/path/foobar.md)
```

- `-P` for non greedy support. The regex should be in perl syntax